# are there any multiple encryption standards?

Tags: cryptography

I'm looking to encrypt some data using multiple ciphers (ie, AES, Serpent, Twofish...), and I want the user to be able to choose which ciphers are used and in what order.  Are there any standards available for defining the metadata?  My understanding is that what I dont want to do is prefix each layer with a magic number indicating the type of cipher and parameters used in the next layer because it will expose me to a plaintext attack.  I took a peak at the PKCS #8 RFC, and it appears that only a single layer of encryption is supported here:

```
  EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    encryptionAlgorithm  EncryptionAlgorithmIdentifier,
    encryptedData        EncryptedData }
```

I suppose I could just define the encryptionAlgorithm to be an array of values, but I want to make sure there isnt already a standard defined somewhere that I have missed.

Comment: why are you allowing users to pick the encryption scheme?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Why not? Users may have preferences and/or requirements. When talking between different systems, different algorithms may or may not be supported -- by user choice or policy. Consider SSH as an example of "letting users pick".

Comment: Because I assume some people will have a preference over Twofish or Serpent (for example).  However, the flexibility would also mean it would be easy for me to change the encryption in the future (ie, introduce AES2 or something)

Comment: senecaso
: enabling you to change it and users to change it, are two very different things.

Comment: True.  What I meant was the client library I would be implementing (which the user would use) could be extended in the future to allow AES2 use.  The plan is that the user has full control of how the data is encrypted.  However, the metadata needs to be common such that other client libraries will be able to decrypt it.  So if client library A uses AES+Serpent, and client library B uses just AES, they need to be able to decrypt each others encrypted data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PKCS#7 and its successor [CMS](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5652.txt) allows for multiple layers. The EncryptedData contains an EncryptedContentInfo that when decrypted can contain another EncryptedData. This is usually used to combine encryption and signing, but there is no reason that it cannot be used for multiple layers of encryption (though support in other implementations may vary).

[XML Encryption](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/) is another common standard for cryptographic metadata. It has no direct support for nesting encryption layers, but since it relies on the specification of the enclosing schema to specify the expected format of the encrypted data, there is no reason it could not specify multiple layers.

The [OpenPGP Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) is the final standardized format I can think of. Like CMS it supports nested layers of encryption (in theory - implementations might or might not support it).

Neither of the formats supports specifying nested encryption-layers upfront: the metadata for the nested layers will be encrypted, so you do not avoid the known-plaintext weakness. However, since you should always choose an algorithm that is safe against known-plaintext attacks anyway, I do not see that as a big problem.

Comment: After looking this up, it appears that AES is deemed safe against known plaintext attacks, but it looks like someone found a known plaintext attack Serpent with 9 rounds (and a huge memory requirement).  Doesnt look like a realistic attack right now.  Thanks!  It sounds like I can just stick with PKCS#8 definition and be fine then, since my concern was including the metadata in the encrypted data.  However, I'm a little confused about your PKCS#8/CMS statement.  Isnt CMS the successor to PKCS#7?

Comment: @senecaso: Sorry, yes that should have been PKCS#7/CMS. Are you encrypting a private key since you are looking into PKCS#8?

Comment: I see.  I didnt specifically say I was encrypting private key data, so your statement about PKCS#7/CMS makes sense.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of, because this isn't a cryptographic best-practice. Select a single, well known and peer reviewed cipher, and use that. Build your code so that you (or your users, rather) can easily swap out existing ciphers for a new one if a compromise is found, but don't expect to nest ciphers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to crypto.. Could you elaborate on why multiple ciphers isnt a best-practice?  I was under the impression that it was ok as long as you didnt introduce plaintext attacks by prefixing/suffixing each layer.

Comment: I should have added, that even if you did introduce a plaintext attack, it would merely reduce the outer layer(s) to being more of a hurdle than an obstacle, but the first layer would remain intact.  Is this not the case?

Comment: @senecaso Increasing the complexity of your system creates more opportunities for there to be a vulnerability in your implementation. At the same time, layering ciphers doesn't provide an appreciable benefit under most threat models: Your data should have a well defined lifetime, and if a cipher you're using is compromised, you want to replace that cipher with a better one as soon as possible regardless of any other ciphers you're using.

Comment: Ok, I certainly understand your point about the increasing complexity.  However, I keep coming back to the "what if XXX cipher is broken in a couple years" scenario and thinking that having a couple different layers could help buy you some time to replace the broken cipher.  Perhaps the increase in complexity isnt offset by the benefit though...

Comment: I'll have to give this more thought.  For the immediate future, I'm sure a single layer of AES256 is good enough to protect the data.  The question becomes, what happens if it fails and do I care if it does, I suppose.

Comment: @senecaso The consequences of failure depend on what you're doing with the data (for example, storing it vs transmitting it) and your threat model. Generally, what you do is stop encrypting the data with the broken cipher and start encrypting it with a new one. Crypto primitives are rarely broken overnight, either - they'll show weakness long before they're compromised, allowing you to start moving to a better cipher.

Comment: The data will be stored, possibly for years.  However, you're right that there would probably be plenty of notice that the cipher was faltering and the user could move to another cipher before there was an issue.  As long as the attacker wasnt able to get a copy of the original cipher text, then re-encrypting with a new cipher would keep the data protected.  Thanks!